# Ionic fail run on android Connection Refused

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm used Ionic 3 and angular 5 to build a gaming score app. all work well on ionic-lab and android emulator.

But when i run it on real device, i always got

net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ( https://192.168.8.101:8100 ) with the same message on app windows.

How can i solve that ?

Comment: I think you are using ionic cordova run android --device command to run this app if you are disconnected from USB you will get this error. 
Try to give command
 ionic cordova build android --prod

Comment: no, i build the apk with `ionic cordova build android --realease', copy it on my phone and install it.

Comment: all your score are loading from the local machine?